# Clicking a href javascript link using python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

This is the element I want to click on using python selenium

```
<a href="javascript:linksubmit()">
```

The text of the link is

"Check Status of Application Materials"

I've been stuck on this for hours.
Tried the following, none worked

```
mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='javascript:linksubmit()']").click()

link = mydriver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Check Status').click()

link = mydriver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title='Check Status of Application Materials']").click()
```

Comment: This seems to be an AJAX call. What did you expect and what did you get? The code is okay, it must work.

Comment: We can't recreate this without some actual HTML. Is this publicly available?